# Cassandra Nodetool TopPartitions error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I am trying to use the **nodetool toppartitions** command to find the top ten partitions over a period of time. However, I don't understand why I receive always this error:

```
$ nodetool toppartitions ycsb usertable 100 
nodetool: Argument value's index, calculated according to this TabularData instance's tabularType, already refers to a value in this table.
See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help <command>'.
```

I am using YCSB as workload generator and Cassandra 3.
Do you know other ways to retrieve the most used partitions or tokens range over a period?

Thanks

Comment: Does your command follow this order?

-> `nodetool toppartitions <keyspace>  <table> <duration>`

-> `nodetool toppartitions ycsb usertable 100 `

Comment: Yes, I am using YCSB workload generator.